# "error signaled in parallel" for functional Index

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am using a functional index in my oracle table ,while running a merge query - records are updating fine but for inserting records it shows the below error:

```
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [rwoirw: check ret val], 
           [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
12801. 00000 -  "error signaled in parallel query server %s"
*Cause:    A parallel query server reached an exception condition.
*Action:   Check the following error message for the cause, and consult your error manual 
           for the appropriate action.
*Comment:  This error can be turned off with event 10397, in which case the server's 
           actual error is signaled instead.
```

**Functional Index Used :** `(SUBSTR("BILL_PROD_SOT_ID",0,INSTR("BILL_PROD_SOT_ID",'_',-1‌​)-1))`

After analysis I have found that this happens due to the `/*+ PARALLEL (APP_PRODUCT_SERVICE,4) */` hash tag in my query, because am inserting through four node configuration.

The record count is too high ,so I am unable to avoid `/*+ PARALLEL (APP_PRODUCT_SERVICE,4) */`

Select query which am using is too long. So I just mentioned brief:

```
MERGE /*+ APPEND */ INTO PRODUCT_SERVICE PS 
 USING ( 
    SELECT /*+ PARALLEL (APP_PRODUCT_SERVICE,4) */ BILL_PROD_SOT_ID, 
           INSTANCE_ID, ...
) ... 
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
  SET PS.BILL_SERV_SOT_ID = UPD.BILL_SERV_SOT_ID,
      PS.INSTANCE_TYPE = UPD.INSTANCE_TYPE,
      PS.CATALOG_PROD_ID = UPD.CATALOG_PROD_ID 
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (INSTANCE_ID ,BILL_SERV_SOT_ID);
```

If I drop the function index it works fine.

Can anyone suggest how to solve this issue?

Comment: Show us the index definition and select statement.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit

 index for this substring 

`(SUBSTR("BILL_PROD_SOT_ID",0,INSTR("BILL_PROD_SOT_ID",'_',-1)-1))`        

**Select query is too long ,just i mentioned brief :**

`MERGE /*+ APPEND */ INTO PRODUCT_SERVICE PS USING (
 SELECT  /*+ PARALLEL (APP_PRODUCT_SERVICE,4) */

  BILL_PROD_SOT_ID,
INSTANCE_ID
, 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
  SET PS.BILL_SERV_SOT_ID = UPD.BILL_SERV_SOT_ID
,PS.INSTANCE_TYPE = UPD.INSTANCE_TYPE
,PS.CATALOG_PROD_ID = UPD.CATALOG_PROD_ID


WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT(INSTANCE_ID
,BILL_SERV_SOT_ID);`

Comment: Edit your question instead of putting it as comment.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit edited

Comment: ora-0600 is an internal error that might indicate a bug. You need to open an issue with Oracle support for that.

Comment: And the question has nothing to do with SQL Developer or PL/SQL Developer

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks . 

But it might be due to Functional index  in my table.,

If i drop that Functional index its working fine .

OR else if  i keep the Functional Index and Removing the hint `/*+ PARALLEL (APP_PRODUCT_SERVICE,4) */` then its working fine.

In my case I need to keep both the above Hint and functional index ,So suggest me any ides .

Comment: Can you tell me version of oracle

Comment: @mohsen.b client-11.2.0

Comment: Dear Dhamodharan, it should be version of database not client. it should like 11.2.0.1 or something like this. please query **v$version**.

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production